# react bootstrap acoordion cannot use pre tag or css white space for new line

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create a accordion for my web app and it have accordion from bootstrap in it.

I wanted my app to be able to create new line depending on the product description entered from the database so if the admin set the desc to enter new line, the accordion should also enter and show newline. I tried using pre tag and also css white-space: pre-wrap but nothing work with it.
Can anyone help me to fix this ?

my code:

```
<Container fluid>
  <Row>
    <Col lg={12} xs={12} className=" fontRegular">
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" >
        <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
            <Accordion.Header className="fontMedium">Deskripsi Produk</Accordion.Header>
            <Accordion.Body className="fontRegular">
              <pre >
                {product.description}
                hello
                hi
              </pre>
            </Accordion.Body>
        </Accordion.Item>
      </Accordion>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you break line with "enter" in some tool, line break signs are inserted. This is for example how it looks like in Notepad++:

[image]

In your code editor line break signs are not automatically inserted, but if you manually do, you will see, that new lines are rendered accordingly:

```
const product = { description: "This is a \r\n Test" };
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-grass-jz8syz

I don't know how your CMS or admin panel looks like, but usually you don't have to worry about your line breaks - this is handled automatically.